# Django save Array of JSON object to database

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am sending AJAX POST request to Django and in the request body data is sent as array of objects.

**Request Payload:**(Javascript)

```
 [{"x":1423182600000},{"x":1423237500000},{"x":1423259100000},{"x":1423281600000},{"x":1423295100000}]
```

On Django side I am reading JSON data like this,

```
def put_flag_data(request):
  res=json.loads(request.body)
  for value in res:
  print  value
```

and the printed value on Django side is as shown below

```
{u'x': 1423182600000L}
{u'x': 1423237500000L}
{u'x': 1423259100000L}
{u'x': 1423281600000L}
{u'x': 1423295100000L}



 class Wildata(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, default=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Wildata'
```

Problem here is the printed value include special char in **{u'x'**. How do I remove this. 
Is there a better way to read and save this list in database?

Comment: Its not an issue 'value' is in dict format ,so its printing with {u'x',

Comment: how do you save list of array objects? do u want model detais

Comment: You at least need to explain where you want to save them.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to save it in mysql database

Comment: Sigh. Do you have models?

Comment: @DanielRoseman update in question please have a look

Comment: So you just want to create new Wildata instances with the `x` value from the JSON files? Leaving the `text` and `title` blank?

Comment: yeah, but sometimes text and title are also requried

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for data in res: 
    Wildata.objects.create(x=days['x'])
```